# La interfaz Comparable

Tags: java, herencia, override

**¡HOLA!**

Tengo que pasar este test unitario

```
    @Test
    public void testCompareTo() {
        try {
            Wrestler romanReigns = new Powerhouse("Leati Joseph \"Joe\" Anoa'i", LocalDate.of(1985, 5, 25),
                    "Pensacola, Florida, U.S.", Gender.MALE, 191, 130, "Roman Reigns");
            romanReigns.setSignature("Spear");
            romanReigns.setFinisher("Superman Punch");

            WrestlerProperties strengthProperties = new StrengthProperties(98, 95);
            WrestlerProperties agilityProperties = new AgilityProperties(80, 80, 60);
            WrestlerProperties staminaProperties = new StaminaProperties(95, 95, 95);
            WrestlerProperties techniqueProperties = new TechniqueProperties(85);
            WrestlerProperties defenseProperties = new DefenseProperties(80, 85, 80, 97);

            WrestlerProperties[] properties = {strengthProperties, agilityProperties, staminaProperties, techniqueProperties, defenseProperties};
            romanReigns.setProperties(properties);

            assertEquals(0, wrestler.compareTo(wrestler));
            assertEquals(0, romanReigns.compareTo(romanReigns));
            assertEquals(-11, wrestler.compareTo(romanReigns));
            assertEquals(11, romanReigns.compareTo(wrestler));

            assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> wrestler.compareTo(null));

        } catch (SuperstarException | WrestlerException ex) {
            fail("There was an error with compareTo: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Classe Wrestler

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Comparable;


public abstract class Wrestler extends Superstar implements Speakable, Comparable<Wrestler>{

    private double strength;
    private double agility;
    private double stamina;
    private double technique;
    private double defense;
    private double energy;
    private String signature;
    private String finisher;
    private boolean isFace;

    private final WrestlerProperties[] properties;

    public static final int ATTRIBUTES_MIN_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE = 96;
    private static final int ATTRIBUTES_SUM_VALUE = 100;
    private static final String DEFAULT_SIGNATURE = "Superkick";
    private static final String DEFAULT_FINISHER = "Canadian Destroyer";

    protected Wrestler(String birthName, LocalDate birthDate, String birthplace,
                    Gender gender, double height, double weight, String ringName,
                    double strength, double agility, double stamina, double technique,
                    double defense) throws SuperstarException, WrestlerException {

        super(birthName, birthDate, birthplace, gender, height, weight, ringName);

        //setBirthName(birthName);
        //setBirthDate(birthDate);
        //setBirthplace(birthplace);
        //setGender(gender);
        //setHeight(height);
        //setWeight(weight);
        //setRingName(ringName);

        this.strength = 20;
        this.agility = 20;
        this.stamina = 20;
        this.technique = 20;
        this.defense = 20;
        this.energy = 100;
        this.signature = DEFAULT_SIGNATURE;
        this.finisher = DEFAULT_FINISHER;
        this.isFace = true;

        this.properties= new WrestlerProperties[5];

        properties[0] = new StrengthProperties(0, 0);
        properties[1] = new AgilityProperties(0,0,0);
        properties[2] = new StaminaProperties(0, 0,0);
        properties[3] = new TechniqueProperties(0);
        properties[4] = new DefenseProperties(0,0,0,0);

        String[] attributes = {"strength", "agility", "stamina", "technique", "defense"};

        for (String attribute : attributes) {
            double value = switch (attribute) {
                case "strength" -> strength;
                case "agility" -> agility;
                case "stamina" -> stamina;
                case "technique" -> technique;
                case "defense" -> defense;
                default -> throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES);
            };

            if (!isAttributeInRange(value)) {
                throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + attribute);
            }
        }
        if (!areAttributesSumInRange()){
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }


    public WrestlerProperties[] setProperties(WrestlerProperties[] properties) throws WrestlerException {
        if (properties == null || Arrays.asList(properties).contains(null)) {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_PROPERTIES_NULL);
        }
        //Els valors a l'atribut properties
        return properties;
    }

    private boolean isAttributeInRange(double value) {
        return value >= ATTRIBUTES_MIN_VALUE && value <= ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE;
    }

    /*
    private boolean areAttributesSumInRange(double strength, double agility, double stamina, double technique, double defense ) {
        return (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) == ATTRIBUTES_SUM_VALUE;
    }
    */
    private boolean areAttributesSumInRange() {
        return (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) == ATTRIBUTES_SUM_VALUE;
    }

    public WeightClass getWeightClass() {
        return WeightClass.getWeightClass(getWeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.print("I'm the best wrestler in the world!!");
    }

    public double getStrength() {return strength;}

    private void setStrength(double strength) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(strength)) {
            this.strength = strength;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + " - strength");
        }
    }



    public double getAgility() {return agility;}

    private void setAgility(double agility) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(agility)) {
            this.agility = agility;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "agility");
        }
    }

    public double getStamina() {return stamina;}

    private void setStamina(double stamina) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(stamina)) {
            this.stamina = stamina;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "stamina");
        }
    }

    public double getTechnique() {return technique;}

    private void setTechnique(double technique) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(technique)) {
            this.technique = technique;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "technique");
        }
    }

    public double getDefense() {return defense;}

    private void setDefense(double defense) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(defense)) {
            this.defense = defense;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "defense");
        }
    }

    public double getEnergy() {return energy;}
    public void setEnergy(double energy) {
        if (energy < 0) {
            this.energy = 0;
        } else if (energy > 100) {
            this.energy = 100;
        } else {
            this.energy = energy;
        }
    }

    public String getSignature() {return signature;}
    public void setSignature(String signature) {
        this.signature = (signature != null) ? signature : DEFAULT_SIGNATURE;
    }

    public String getFinisher() {return finisher;}
    public void setFinisher(String finisher) {
        this.finisher = (finisher != null) ? finisher : DEFAULT_FINISHER;
    }

    public boolean isFace() {return isFace;}
    public void setFace(boolean face) {this.isFace = face;}


    public double getOverall() {
    double average = (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) / 5.0;
    return Math.round(average * 10.0) / 10.0;
}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        return getRingName().toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBirth name: " + getBirthName() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBorn: " + getBirthDate().format(dateFormatter) + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t      " + getBirthplace() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tSignature: " + signature + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tFinisher: " + finisher + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tOverall: 0.0";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Wrestler wrestler) {
        if (wrestler == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Cannot compare with a null wrestler");
        }

        //Comparar pel valor de getOverall
        double thisOverall = this.getOverall();
        double otherOverall = wrestler.getOverall();

        //Ordre descendent
        return Double.compare(otherOverall, thisOverall);
    }

}
```

El atributo properties será un array donde su primer valor almacenará un objeto de tipo StrengthProperties, el segundo un objeto AgilityProperties, el tercero StaminaProperties, el cuarto TechniqueProperties y el quinto DefenseProperties.

```
    private final WrestlerProperties[] properties;

        this.properties= new WrestlerProperties[5];

        properties[0] = new StrengthProperties(0, 0);
        properties[1] = new AgilityProperties(0,0,0);
        properties[2] = new StaminaProperties(0, 0,0);
        properties[3] = new TechniqueProperties(0);
        properties[4] = new DefenseProperties(0,0,0,0);
```

El método getOverall devuelve la media ponderada de las propiedades del luchador.Cada conjunto de propiedades almacenado en el atributo properties debe ser ponderado por el peso de la propiedad (valor indicado por los atributos strength, agility, stamina, technique y defense, respectivamente). El valor resultante debe estar redondeado.

```
public double getOverall() {
    double average = (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) / 5.0;
    return Math.round(average * 10.0) / 10.0;
}
```

Esta clase implementa la interfaz Comparable, que es una interfaz de la API Java.Esto nos obliga a sobreescribir el método compareTo. Gracias a compareTo estamos diciendo en la clase que implementa Comparable cómo comparar dos objetos que pertenecen a esta clase.

En el caso de mi clase Wrestler queremos que este método indique cuál de los dos objetos va primero en orden teniendo en cuenta que debe priorizar aquel que tiene más media ( más valor al invocar el método getOverall). Si el objeto pasado como parámetro es null, el método compareTo debe lanzar la excepción de Java NullPointerException sin mensaje.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Wrestler wrestler) {
    if (wrestler == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    
    Double thisOverall = this.getOverall();
    Double otherOverall = wrestler.getOverall();
    
    return otherOverall.compareTo(thisOverall);
}
```

Pregunta actualizada. Gracias!

**BUEN INICIO DE SEMANA**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No deberias devolver la comparacion? porque estas llamando a compareTo, que llama a compareTo, que llama a compareTo... y quien hace la comparacion?

Comment: @gbianchi Wrestler.compareTo está llamando a Double.compareTo, no hay recursividad infinita ahí

Comment: @RubioRic tenes razon.. mala mia...

Comment: Cual es el error que esta largando? que comparacion no funciona?

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede estar en estas líneas

```
assertEquals(-11, wrestler.compareTo(romanReigns));
assertEquals(11, romanReigns.compareTo(wrestler));
```

De acuerdo con el [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compareTo-java.lang.Double-) de la clase Double, el método `compareTo` devuelve

> the value 0 if anotherDouble is numerically equal to this Double;
>  a
> value less than 0 if this Double is numerically less than
> anotherDouble;
>  and a value greater than 0 if this Double is
> numerically greater than anotherDouble.

Que en español sería que devuelve

> 0 si anotherDouble es numéricamente igual a this
> Un número menor que 0 si this es numéricamente menor que anotherDouble
> Un número mayor que 0 si this es numéricamente mayor que anotherDouble

Si te fijas, no dice que devuelva exactamente -11 ni 11, que es lo que tú tienes en los assert. Tienes que cambiar esas líneas para que comprueben si lo devuelto es negativo o positivo.

Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo con dos Doubles cuya diferencia es exactamente 11, por buscarle alguna razón a esos assert

```
public class CompareDouble {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double mayor = Double.valueOf(12);
        Double menor = Double.valueOf(1);

        System.out.println(mayor.compareTo(menor));
        System.out.println(menor.compareTo(mayor));
    }
}
```

Al ejecutarlo obtengo esta salida

[image: salida obtenida]

Como ves sale 1 y -1, pero nadie garantiza esa salida exacta. Es positivo y negativo lo que garantiza el javadoc.

Con el código que has incluido no puedo reproducir tu ejemplo, no sé exactamente qué implicaciones tiene la clase Powerhouse. Si simplificas las clases de forma que tengamos un ejemplo mínimo ejecutable, podriamos probarlo.

Por último, deberías añadir a tu pregunta el mensaje de error que te está dando el test al ejecutarse.

---

A ver, después de tus actualizaciones y como te indicaba en diversos comentarios: Si únicamente en el constructor de la clase Wrestler es donde estableces los valores de los que depende Overall

```
this.strength = 20;
this.agility = 20;
this.stamina = 20;
this.technique = 20;
this.defense = 20;
this.energy = 100;
```

entonces romanReigns.getOverall() siempre es igual que wrestler.getOverall, con lo cual compareTo siempre te devuelve cero.

En tus requisitos tiene que haber algo que indique que un Powerhouse tiene más fuerza que un Wrestler básico, de forma que la comparación devuelva que un wrestler es menor que un powerhouse de forma que se cumplan los asserts de arriba.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Wrestler wrestler) {
    if (wrestler == null) {
           throw new NullPointerException();
    }
        
    Double thisOverall = this.getOverall();  // Esto da 20
    Double otherOverall = wrestler.getOverall(); // Esto da 20
        
    return otherOverall.compareTo(thisOverall); // 20 es igual a 20 -> Esto devuelve 0 siempre
}
```

¿No tienes ningún test para tus métodos setProperties y getOverall para tus distintas clases? Deberían estar fallándote.

---

Mira, seguramente tienes que completar el método setProperties con algo como esto

```
public WrestlerProperties[] setProperties(WrestlerProperties[] properties) throws WrestlerException {
   if (properties == null || Arrays.asList(properties).contains(null)) {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_PROPERTIES_NULL);
   }

   StrengthProperties strengthProperties = (StrengthProperties) properties[0];
   int media = (strengthProperties.getStrength1() + strengthProperties.getStrength2()) / 15;
   setStrength(media);

   //Els valors a l'atribut properties
   return properties;
}
```

De forma que cuando se establezcan las propiedades de un luchador, sus características cambien. Ahí he cambiado la fuerza, por hacer algo. Tú deberías recalcular ahí todas las características que sean. Con ese pequeño cambio y cambiando -11 y 11 por -1 y 1, respectivamente, el test pasa. Te insisto, lo de -11 y 11 es una errata.

Aunque debería ser

```
assertTrue(wrestler.compareTo(romanReigns) < 0); // wrestler es menor que romanReigns
assertTrue(romanReigns.compareTo(wrestler) > 0); // romanReigns es mayor que wrestler.
```

Esto último se lo puedes comentar a tu profesor de mi parte.

Answer (score -1):

**Gracias por reponder**

El mensaje de error del test unitario:

```
Expected :-11
Actual   :0
```

Sí, la linea de error esta en:

```
assertEquals(-11, wrestler.compareTo(romanReigns));
assertEquals(11, romanReigns.compareTo(wrestler));
```

Clase Powerhouse

> NOTA: La clase Powerhouse pasa correctamente su respectivo test unitario.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Powerhouse extends Wrestler {


    // Constructor
    public Powerhouse(String birthName, LocalDate birthDate, String birthplace, Gender gender,
                     double height, double weight, String ringName) throws WrestlerException {
        super(birthName, birthDate, birthplace, gender, height, weight, ringName, 30, 10, 25, 15, 20);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        return getRingName().toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBirth name: " + getBirthName() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBorn: " + getBirthDate().format(dateFormatter) + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t      " + getBirthplace() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tSignature: " + getSignature() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tFinisher: " + getFinisher() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tStyle: " + "Powerhouse" + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tOverall: 90.0"; //MALAMENT
    }

}
```

Si no es mucha molestia adjunto toda la clase principal, Wrestler:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Comparable;


public abstract class Wrestler extends Superstar implements Speakable, Comparable<Wrestler>{

    private double strength;
    private double agility;
    private double stamina;
    private double technique;
    private double defense;
    private double energy;
    private String signature;
    private String finisher;
    private boolean isFace;

    private WrestlerProperties[] properties;

    public static final int ATTRIBUTES_MIN_VALUE = 1;
    public static final int ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE = 96;
    private static final int ATTRIBUTES_SUM_VALUE = 100;
    private static final String DEFAULT_SIGNATURE = "Superkick";
    private static final String DEFAULT_FINISHER = "Canadian Destroyer";


    protected Wrestler(String birthName, LocalDate birthDate, String birthplace,
                    Gender gender, double height, double weight, String ringName,
                    double strength, double agility, double stamina, double technique,
                    double defense) throws SuperstarException, WrestlerException {

        super(birthName, birthDate, birthplace, gender, height, weight, ringName);

        this.strength = 20;
        this.agility = 20;
        this.stamina = 20;
        this.technique = 20;
        this.defense = 20;
        this.energy = 100;
        this.signature = DEFAULT_SIGNATURE;
        this.finisher = DEFAULT_FINISHER;
        this.isFace = true;

        this.properties= new WrestlerProperties[5];

        properties[0] = new StrengthProperties(0, 0);
        properties[1] = new AgilityProperties(0,0,0);
        properties[2] = new StaminaProperties(0, 0,0);
        properties[3] = new TechniqueProperties(0);
        properties[4] = new DefenseProperties(0,0,0,0);

        String[] attributes = {"strength", "agility", "stamina", "technique", "defense"};

        for (String attribute : attributes) {
            double value = switch (attribute) {
                case "strength" -> strength;
                case "agility" -> agility;
                case "stamina" -> stamina;
                case "technique" -> technique;
                case "defense" -> defense;
                default -> throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES);
            };

            if (!isAttributeInRange(value)) {
                throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + attribute);
            }
        }

        if (!areAttributesSumInRange(strength, agility, stamina, technique, defense)) {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }

    public double getEnergy() {return energy;}
    public void setEnergy(double energy) {
        if (energy < 0) {
            this.energy = 0;
        } else if (energy > 100) {
            this.energy = 100;
        } else {
            this.energy = energy;
        }
    }

    public String getSignature() {return signature;}
    public void setSignature(String signature) {
        this.signature = (signature != null) ? signature : DEFAULT_SIGNATURE;
    }

    public String getFinisher() {return finisher;}
    public void setFinisher(String finisher) {
        this.finisher = (finisher != null) ? finisher : DEFAULT_FINISHER;
    }

    public boolean isFace() {return isFace;}
    public void setFace(boolean face) {this.isFace = face;}

    public WrestlerProperties[] setProperties(WrestlerProperties[] properties) throws WrestlerException {
        if (properties == null || Arrays.asList(properties).contains(null)) {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_PROPERTIES_NULL);
        }
        //Els valors a l'atribut properties
        return properties;
    }




    public WeightClass getWeightClass() {
        return WeightClass.getWeightClass(getWeight());
    }


    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.print("I'm the best wrestler in the world!!");}



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

        return getRingName().toUpperCase() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBirth name: " + getBirthName() + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tBorn: " + getBirthDate().format(dateFormatter) + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\t      " + getBirthplace() +
                "\tSignature: " + signature + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tFinisher: " + finisher + System.lineSeparator() +
                "\tOverall: " + getOverall();
    }

    //Overriding compareTo() method
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Wrestler wrestler) {
        if (wrestler == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        //Comparar pel valor de getOverall
        Double thisOverall = this.getOverall();
        Double otherOverall = wrestler.getOverall();

        //Ordre descendent
        return otherOverall.compareTo(thisOverall);
    }


    private boolean isAttributeInRange(double value) {
        return value >= ATTRIBUTES_MIN_VALUE && value <= ATTRIBUTES_MAX_VALUE;
    }

    private boolean areAttributesSumInRange(double strength, double agility, double stamina, double technique, double defense) {
        return (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) == ATTRIBUTES_SUM_VALUE;
    }

    public double getStrength() {return strength;}

    private void setStrength(double strength) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(strength)) {
            this.strength = strength;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "strength");
        }
    }

    public double getAgility() {return agility;}

    private void setAgility(double agility) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(agility)) {
            this.agility = agility;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "agility");
        }
    }

    public double getStamina() {return stamina;}

    private void setStamina(double stamina) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(stamina)) {
            this.stamina = stamina;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "stamina");
        }
    }

    public double getTechnique() {return technique;}

    private void setTechnique(double technique) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(technique)) {
            this.technique = technique;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "technique");
        }
    }

    public double getDefense() {return defense;}

    private void setDefense(double defense) throws WrestlerException {
        if (isAttributeInRange(defense)) {
            this.defense = defense;
        } else {
            throw new WrestlerException(WrestlerException.MSG_ERR_ATTRIBUTES_VALUES + "defense");
        }
    }

public double getOverall() {
    double average = (strength + agility + stamina + technique + defense) / 5.0;
    return Math.round(average * 10.0) / 10.0;
}




}
```

¡Gracias!

**BUENAS NOCHES**

Comment: Buenas, Arianna, ese 0 quiere decir que el método toCompare te está devolviendo que son iguales pero supuestamente no deberían. ¿Puedes incluir la inicialización de la variable wrestler que se usa en el test? Pero edita tu pregunta, por favor, has incluido toda esta nueva información como si fuera una respuesta. Es válido responderse uno mismo pero esto no soluciona tu problema. Si "mueves" toda la info de aquí más esa inicialización que falta, mañana a ver si puedo reproducirlo. Salud!

Comment: De todas formas, lo que te respondía sigue siendo válido: la comparación de los Double puede que no devuelva -11 cuando lo arregles.

Comment: Nah, no puedo, me faltan demasiadas clases ... Un posible origen de tus fallos es que el método setProperties no modifica los atributos del luchador (fuerza, agilidad, etc) ... Si no recalculas dichos atributos, probablemente wrestler y powerhouse tengan los mismos valores que se establecen en el constructor, con lo cual sus overall serán siempre iguales. Pero vamos, Céntrate en resolver un problema, si abres muchas preguntas en paralelo teniendo un escenario con tantas clases es muy dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Tú eres la única que puede ver que está pasando si ejecutas el test en modo debug y pones un punto de ruptura en getOverall. ¿Qué valores tienen ahí los atributos? ¿Qué valor es el que se supone que tiene que devolver?

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo casi todo para poder ejecutar el test, me falta el wrestler, que supongo que es un Superstar pero no sé sus características ni que implica ser un Superstar. En cualquier caso: los asserts están mal (ver mi respuesta), el método getOverall está mal (te fallan varios tests por su causa), el método setProperties quizás debería hacer algo más ...

Comment: No pongas una respuesta si es una edicion a tu pregunta, es muy dificil tratar de ayudarte asi..

Comment: Perdona, es la primera vez que publico aquí.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar la pregunta, con la clase completa de Wrestler, que es classe que tiene que pasar el test unitario; junto al atributo properties.

Comment: Buenas, Arianna, he actualizado yo también mi respuesta de arriba. He detallado algo más lo que te indicaba en todos mis comentarios. Leelo atentamente y cualquier cosa me comentas ahí arriba. Salud!